# Triangle law of vector addition for parallel vectors

Tags: vectors

It says in my textbook that we cannot use the parallelogram law of addition for two parallel vectors, but the triangle law always applies, I didn't get this at all. How does the triangle law apply if two vectors, or two sides of the triangle, are parallel to each other? And if you guys say that it is a duplicate of any other question, then please explain why.

Comment: what if they are antiparallel?

Comment: This has an answer (with diagrams) in this [Mathematics SE question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268147/what-is-the-difference-between-triangle-law-and-parallelogram-law-of-addition-of).  The key point is where you put the start of each vector and how being parallel complicates the parallelogram rule.

Comment: Can you consider two vectors directed along the same line parallel  ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you already see that the parallelogram rule won't work with parallel vectors.

But in the triangle law you graphically add vectors by placing the tail of one on the tip of the other, and the resultant is the vector going from the tail of the first one to the tip of the second one.    The magnitude of the resultant is calculated algebraically as $R=\sqrt {a^2+b^2-2ab 
cos\theta}$.  You can do  all of that with parallel vectors (when placed tip to tail, $\theta$ is 180°).